# Replace newlines to word using regex?

Tags: regex

I Replace newlines to word using regex? itry this regex code but not working `(.*+)/g` this is my regex https://regex101.com/r/bW1gN3/2

Input:

```
one

two



three


four


five
```

Output:

```
one
one
two
two
two
two
three
three
three
four
four
four
four
five
```

Comment: So, you should keep just one new line character? Or, all new lines should be removed? Like this: https://regex101.com/r/bW1gN3/3?

Comment: @nevermind yes, i want to replace every character above the newlines So on and so forth..

Comment: no, not like that @nevermind

Comment: In which language/tool are you doing this?

Comment: @anubhava im using jquery

Comment: "jQuery" is not a programming language. From `[tag:jquery]`: "jQuery is a popular cross-browser **JavaScript** library ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GREP on itself cannot do this, but since you are using not pure GREP but an actual programming language, you can use `replace`:

```
str = "one\n\ntwo\n\n\n\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\n\nfive";
str = str.replace (/(.+)\n+/g, function (a,b) { return a.replace(/.*\n/g, b+'\n'); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that this cannot be done with one regex. You can use a while loop:

```
var str = "one\n\ntwo\n\n\n\nthree\n\n\nfour\n\n\nfive\n";
var regex = /(.+)(\n+)/gi;
var str2 = "";

while (result = regex.exec(str))
    str2 += result[2].replace(/\n/g, result[1] + "\n");
```